# How to insert data into table using different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

There is one table,

```
t1(network,totalCount,partialCount)
```

The other table is,

```
t2(network,isPartial,count)
```

Example:

```
T1
network,totalCount,partialCount
  1        100         70
  2        200         130

T2
network,isPartial,Count
   3      Y        78
   3      N        200
   4      Y        150
   4      N        300     

Resulting T1 table after T2 rows are inserted
 network,totalCount,partialCount
  1        100         70
  2        200         130
  3        200         78
  4        300         150
```

The condition should be:

- If `t2.isPartial = 'Y'` insert the data into `t1.partialCount`.
- If `t2.isPartial = 'N'` insert the data into `t1.totalCount`.

So what should I do to make this implemented in SQL or Stored Procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to define the events with which each condition is allowed to be true. Upon inserting a row into T2? Upon updating a T2 row's isPartial?

Comment: you can use case statement like 

    CASE WHEN isPartial = 'Y'  
    THEN 100 (or whatever value is)
    Else null END

Comment: @jeff6times7     I mean use sql or sql procedure to implement this function not using the events.  Insert into t1 select *from t2  using the above rules.

Comment: @WadeChen If you are not going to use triggers, then you'll want to use a stored procedure.

Comment: @Imranbutt   I wonder how this case statement achieve this function? Would you provider me with the detailed info?  Really thanks!

Comment: @jeff6times7  It is ok to use procedure, but I am not sure how to write the releated sql..

Comment: Is it fixed that you will have exactly two entries for each network in `T2` table ? One with `Y` and another with `N` ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Only Y and N in T2 table for each network.

Comment: @WadeChen You need to make an attempt to write the shell of your procedure, even if it has a `null` body. Once you get that far, you'll be able to write your own if statement to execute the correct `insert ...on duplicate key update` statement.

Comment: I am asking about your existing data in `T2`. Is it fixed there are exactly two entries for each network - one with `Y` and another with `N`? Like you have two entries for 3 - one with `Y` and another with `N`, same for 4.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Only two entry Y and N

Comment: @jeff6times7 Thanks for your reminder , but all I consider now is.. how to insert the t2 to t1..  I have no idea.  and as for the null body,  it will not happen on the business logic.

Comment: @WadeChen You have to start somewhere. If you have no idea how to write a procedure, then you start with creating a procedure that does nothing. Then you build from there. You make the decision to run the procedure to insert a row into T2 (and then T1) or you write the procedure to process the rows after they have already been inserted. Or, I suppose, if the rows are already in the table, then you could aggregate T2 rows and execute the `insert...on duplicate key update` statement.

Comment: @jeff6times7  I almostly finished the stored procedure ,but still no idea to handle this issue.  I will insert on duplicate key update to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming T1 has primary key (network) and you have finished loading rows into T2 and none of the networks in T2 are in T1:

```
insert into T1 (network, totalCount, partialCount)
select network,
       sum(case ispartial when 'N' then count else 0 end),
       sum(case ispartial when 'Y' then count else 0 end)
from T2
group by network;
```

If there exists at least one row in T2 that has a matching T1, then you'll probably have to write a procedure to loop through the query's output because I don't think MySQL's insert command syntax allows for a subquery along with the `on duplicate key` clause.

Comment: This works well for me.<pre>select t1.network_group_id,sum(case is_facility WHEN 'Y' THEN totalCount ELSE 0 end ),SUM(case WHEN is_facility = 'N' THEN totalCount ELSE 0 end) from (SELECT state_abbr_id,network_group_id, is_facility, count(DISTINCT provider_id) as totalCount
FROM pv_mview_provider_address
WHERE network_group_id = 10 and state_abbr_id = 35
GROUP BY network_group_id, is_facility) t1
group by t1.network_group_id </pre>

Comment: @WadeChen The statement in your comment is not the easiest thing to read because comment formatting is restricted. But it looks like you're saying the query in your comment is your solution. If so, it appears to be a solution for a different problem. And if that is true, then you should not accept my answer and, unfortunately, your question should be downvoted. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I use the subquery to select the result first, and you suggest to use sum , so the suggestion you recommended have the good performance on my business logic. I sum after the subquery, so it is not a issue for performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query like this

```
 insert into network2(network,totalcount,partialcount)

select n.network,CASE WHEN n.ispartial = 'Y'  
THEN n.count
Else null END,
CASE WHEN n.isPartial = 'N'  
THEN  n.count
Else null END 
from network1 n
```

**Update**
I have Tested it here is Network 1 Table

```
Id  network ispartial   count
1   3   Y   100
2   3   N   200
3   4   Y   150
4   4   N   200
```

after executing query network 2

```
Id  network totalcount  partialcount
    1   3   100 NULL
    2   3   NULL    200
    3   4   150 NULL
    4   4   NULL    200
```

Comment: @jeff6times7 Yes I tested it

Comment: @Imranbutt Then why is the column `network` missing from the list of columns in the insert?

Comment: @jeff6times7 you can add column in query like select n.network.....
the test tables I made don't have network column

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by running two queries first select from t2 where t1="Y" and insert into t1 then update t1 where isPartial ="N". In t1 network is unique.

```
   INSERT INTO t1 SELECT t2.* FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.network = t2.network WHERE t2.isPartial="Y"; 
 UPDATE t1 t1, t2 t2 SET t1.totalCount = t2.count WHERE t2.isPartial = "N" and t1.network=t2.network;
```